# Which are the spectral lines used to calculate the redshift?

Tags: spectroscopy, redshift

I'm not sure if this is correct but I read in an article that the light of a distant star is first passed through a tube containing hydrogen gas and then through the prism for getting the absorption lines of Hydrogen. However, doesn't the atmosphere of the star itself have different elements (hydrogen, helium, etc.) which already absorb the frequencies of light according to their properties? I believe then the light as it is emitted from the star should already have absorption lines, whose redshift could be studied without passing through any additional gas. I'm a bit confused regarding the process used. Is the composition of the star first figured out from the spectral line spacings and then the shift observed?

Comment: You basically have it right: the lines are already there. See, for example, [this](https://britastro.org/observations/observation.php?id=20210523_133419_7c841b5f6ae93112) for a comparison of the Sun and three stars.

Comment: Speaking of lines already being there, check out the high resolution solar spectrum pdfs here: https://bass2000.obspm.fr/solar_spect.php. Astronomers are amazingly good and thorough!

Comment: You should cite where you read this. normally a telescope with spectral analysis attached does not use a tube with hydrogen, even if it would not absorb much of the light.So your information seems poor.